# Simple PHP out of Wordpress Array / Object

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my code

```
$getcatid = get_the_category($id);
$postisin = $getcatid;
echo print_r($postisin);
```

This returns:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => stdClass Object ( 
     [term_id] => 8 
     [name] => High Net Worth Individuals     
     [slug] => high-net-worth-individuals 
     [term_group] => 0 
     [term_taxonomy_id] => 8 
     [taxonomy] => category 
     [description] => 
     [parent] => 7 
     [count] => 1 
     [object_id] => 1266 
     [cat_ID] => 8 
     [category_count] => 1 
     [category_description] => 
     [cat_name] => High Net Worth Individuals 
     [category_nicename] => high-net-worth-individuals 
     [category_parent] => 7 
    ) 
) 1
```

**All that I want to do is grab the [term_id] and assign it as a variable to be used later.**

In this case, '8' I'm not the best with PHP, but it's been a while since I've worked with Arrays / Objects and I've been unable to find a solution. I have also lost my Lynda login information > < Help please?

Comment: The "used later" is ambiguous here, you did not mention if to use it in the same page or a different page. Use a variable to store data if you plan to use it in the same page ore use a session variable to store the data if you need it to be used in a different PHP page.

Comment: I see your point, I should've clarified it to use as a variable in a string on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
$postisin[0]->term_id
```

Comment: Ahhh, was trying to write it like `$getcatid = get_the_category($id);
$postisin = $getcatid[term_id];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$termId = $postisin[0]->term_id;
```

Comment: @MichaelRoach lol, javascript too much, that's why :D. Edited answer

Comment: My small use of PHP is based entirely in Wordpress themes and researching documentation / functions now. I haven't written pure PHP for a couple years now, I've forgotten some of the basic stuff. I tried javascript but the syntax destroys me!

Answer (score 0):

use loop

```
foreach ( $postisin as $rows ) {
     echo $rows->term_id;
}
```

or if you want to echo only one index you can use

```
echo $postision[0]->term_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I thought of running a foreach, but it was the only value I needed.